# extract font name and display with quotation mark

Tags: php, regex

how can extract font name only from variable and remove "+"

```
$font = 'Advent+Pro:100,200,300,regular,500,600,700';
```

inline style

```
echo '<style>
.selector {
font-family:'.$font.';
}
</style>
';
```

output must be `font-family:'Advent Pro';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to guess the general form of your problem, but :

You can detect the position of your `:` with `strpos`, get a substring with `substr` and replace your `+` by a space with `str_replace`.

```
$font = 'Advent+Pro:100,200,300,regular,500,600,700';
$font = str_replace ('+', ' ', substr ($font , 0, strpos ($font, ':')));
echo $font;
```

This is only extracting the font family name. If you want to have your quotes around this family name you can either add them in your code :

```
echo '<style>
.selector {
font-family:\''.$font.'\';
}
</style>
';
```

or add them in mine (even if I think this first solution is better) :

```
$font = 'Advent+Pro:100,200,300,regular,500,600,700';
$font = '\'' . str_replace ('+', ' ', substr ($font , 0, strpos ($font, ':'))) . '\'';
echo $font;
```

Note that you have to escape the quote if it is already your string delimiter : `'\''`. You can use double quotes as string delimiters to avoid this : `"'"`.

Please see :

- http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strpos.php for `strpos`
- http://php.net/manual/fr/function.substr.php for `substr`
- and http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str_replace.php for `str_replace`

Comment: thanks but your code output without quotation mark .selector {font-family:Advent Pro;}

Comment: Indeed. You can either modify your code and add quotes : `font-family:\''.$font.'\';` or modify my code to add quotes around the var : `$font = "'" . str_replace … ))) . "'";`. I'm editing my answer right now.

Comment: Like that `$font = '"' . str_replace ('+', ' ', substr ($font , 0, strpos ($font, ':'))) . '"';`